# Transfer photos from Flickr to Google Drive without downloading

Tags: file-transfer, google-drive, flickr

Is there a way to transfer my photos from Flickr to Google Drive without downloading all the data onto my computer - maybe using a Web Service?

Comment: One is ran by Yahoo the other Google they are unlikely to talk to one another.  Just save you a great deal of troule and download the data and upload it to Google Drive.

Comment: @Stan Could [this](http://wappwolf.com/gdriveautomator/) be what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pixelpipe](http://pi.pe) is great for transferring your images between various photo sharing sites.

> The feature allows you to quickly select any photos, video or audio files that are currently hosted on Pixelpipe & export them in bulk to a selection of 20 of our most popular services.

Comment: That site appears to be down :(

Answer (score 1):

http://www.flickrtoplus.com/ is a pretty simple 3-step online wizard which authorises to both flickr and google and copies over your sets.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.flickandshare.com/ Allows you to download your sets, you can then re-upload them however you like.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.picbackman.com/flickr-photo-video-bulk-uploader/ is an apt solution to migrate your Flickr photos to Google Drive or any other online account like Facebook, SmugMug, Dropbox OneDrive etc.